# Monitor Mbean using JMX_Exporter

Tags: java, devops, prometheus, jmx, jmx-exporter

I'm using [JMX_Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/issues) for monitoring Mbeans exposed by my application.
I have the Mbean with ObjetName `com.production.swee.cis:name=CircuitBreaker` and for this Mbean I want to monitor below attributes:

[image: Attributes shown in VisualVM]

1. CircuitTripped
2. FailureCount
3. FailureEntries
4. FailureEntryTimeout
5. FailureLimit

I have configured JMX_Exporter like below:

```
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
lowercaseOutputName: true
whitelistObjectNames:
 - "--other ObjectNames --"
 - "com.production.swee.cis:Name=CircuitBreaker"
rules:
--other rules--
- pattern: 'com.production.swee.cis<Name=CircuitBreaker><>(\w+):'
  name: jmx_circuitbreaker
  labels:
    name: "$1"
  help: jmx_CircuitBreaker_status
  type: GAUGE
```

For some reason my metric does not return any data.Looks like `whitelistObjectNames` or my pattern are not matching.

I even tried:

```
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
lowercaseOutputName: true
whitelistObjectNames:
 - "--other ObjectNames --"
 - "com.production.swee.cis:Name=CircuitBreaker"
rules:
--other rules--
- pattern: '(.*)'
  name: jmx_circuitbreaker
  labels:
    name: "$1"
  help: jmx_CircuitBreaker_status
  type: GAUGE
```

Any hint so far?